# Regular expression for matching string templates

Tags: c#, regex

Required regular expression to match two template by excluding {#var#}

{#var#} can contain anything including special char,unicode char

Example:

Template 1: Dear {#var#},\n Your order {#var#} has been shipped at {#var#} Thank You

Match above template by excluding {#var#} with

Template 2: Dear John,\n Your order 12001222 has been shipped at 15/03/2021 10:30AM Thank You

**If use brackets like ()[] in template text then it does not matched**

```
public static void Main()
{   
     //"Dear {#var#},\n Your (order) {#var#} has been shipped at {#var#} Thank You"
     //Not Working "Dear John,\n Your (order) 12001222 has been shipped at 15/03/2021 10:30AM Thank You";

     bool IsMatched = false;
     string Template="Dear John,\n Your order 12001222 has been shipped at 15/03/2021 10:30AM Thank You";
     string TemplateRegex=@"Dear ([ऀ-ॿa-zA-Z0-9áéíóú@#%&',:.\s-\)\(\]\[\/]+)\,\n Your order ([ऀ-ॿa-zA-Z0-9áéíóú@#%&',:.\s-\)\(\]\[\/]+)\ has been shipped at ([ऀ-ॿa-zA-Z0-9áéíóú@#%&',:.\s-\)\(\]\[\/]+)\ Thank You$";

     Match match = Regex.Match(Template,TemplateRegex,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
     if (match.Success)
         Console.WriteLine("Template Matched");
     else 
         Console.WriteLine("Template not Matched");
}
```

fiddle example
https://dotnetfiddle.net/ugPVKt

Comment: You can simplify your regex using Unicode 
general categories or named blocks https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-classes-in-regular-expressions#supported-unicode-general-categories. I find templates easier to manage with just `StringBuilder.Repace`

Comment: Did you know that C# already has a facility for doing this? Store your string like `Dear {0},\n Your order {1:000000} has been shipped at {2:dd/MM/yyyy HH:mmtt} Thank You` then you can just `string.Format(template, Person.Name, order.Num, order.ShipDateTime)` - note the in-template formatting of the datetime and order number; it's more flexible than having to recompile the app to change it; just keep the format in the template in the db or wherever. Note; I wrote `\n` but that should be stored as a literal newline, not as slash n

Comment: Oh.. unless this is going the other way and you're trying to eg parse an email that someone else has sent you, in which case why make life so complex.. just do `var m = Regex.Match(email, "Dear (?<n>.*),\n Your order (?<o>.*) has been shipped at (?<d>.*) Thank You")` and look in the match's Groups collection for groups named `n`, `o` and `d` which are your name, ordernumber and date respectively

Comment: Can the name include a comma? If not then simplify the piece of the regex between `Dear ` and `,` to just `[^,]+`. Similarly the order number and date-time are very unlikely to be made from many characters, so simplify them. Your regex might be as simple as `Dear ([^,]+)\,\n Your order (\w+) has been shipped at ([\d/]+ [\d:]+[ap]m) Thank You$`. But that does not allow for minor variations in the use of spaces and newlines.

Comment: Why does the regex in the question have backslash characters before comma and spaces?